# Broken images when seeding database on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Rails 4 application that uses paperclip to attach photos.  My db/seeds.rb file adds some photos for my Person model with lines like this:

```
Person.create(:first_name => 'Jon', :last_name => 'Snow', 
      :photo => File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/jon-snow.png))
```

In my app/models/person.rb file I have the :photo as a paperclip attachment where it is cropped and resized:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, 
  :styles => { :medium => "256x256#", :small => "64x64#", :tiny => "24x24#" },
            :default_url => :set_default_avatar,
            :url  => "/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
            :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
```

My problem is that when I try to deploy this to heroku (with the Cedar stack) and then seed the database, the images all come up as broken.  However, on my local computer everything comes up completely fine.

The broken image tag that is generated on heroku might look something like:

```
<img alt="Jon Snow" src="/assets/photos/21/small/jon-snow.png?1386825683">
```

Does anyone know why this link would break on heroku but not on my computer?  I know that heroku is generating the resized photos because the heroku console outputs things similar to what is in this post: [Seed images in heroku with paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949143/seed-images-in-heroku-with-paperclip).
However, it is putting them into public/assets instead of in public/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension as the controller specifies.

I've tried doing what that linked post mentions, as well as running:

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

and a number of other things, but nothing works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I should mention that uploading files manually to heroku from the web page works fine.  But seeding the database is where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the same I described in this answer [How to use paperclip with rails and how does it work in deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523949/how-to-use-paperclip-with-rails-and-how-does-it-work-in-deployment/20524191#20524191)

The [legacy Bamboo stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bamboo) had a [read-only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) so you were unable to write on the file-system.

In the [new Cedar stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar), the file system is no longer read-only, so the upload will not fail. However, you should keep using AWS or any other external storage because Heroku distributes your compiled application across several machines, and it's not guaranteed that the image will be visible from another request. They call it [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

In other words, **you should keep using AWS or any other storage outside Heroku file-system**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I might have to just go with AWS.  But how can it be that files that are uploaded through the web interface show up just fine, whereas ones that are created through db seeding are broken?  If they were all just stored in some caching system on heroku that wasn't distributed, wouldn't all of them show up as broken?

Comment: Because it's likely that the machine you are connecting (and saving the files) when you access Heroku via console it's not the one you are connected to when using the HTTP interface.

Answer (score 0):

From [heroku-dev](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem)

> The filesystem for the slug is read-only, which means you cannot
>   dynamically write to the filesystem for semi-permanent storage. The
>   following types of behaviors are not supported: Caching pages in the
>   public directory Saving uploaded assets to local disk (e.g. with
>   attachment_fu or **paperclip**)

Use [AWS S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#s3-setup)

Comment: I'm working with offthewahls on this project, and that comment only applies to the bamboo stack. This project is on the Cedar stack.

Comment: please indicate this on the issue since it is important. I could be wrong but: there is only one writeable folder on Heroku and this is the tmp folder that you should configure as a tmp folder for your uploads as well.